# How to choose my graphic cards as a source in pavu control if it is not listed?

Tags: sound, xfce, gpu, pavucontrol, cinelerra

my system:
ubuntu 16.04 suite
nvidia gtx 1050 ti

Usually when I run a newly installed program, it has no sound. However, this is simply fixed, I just run it and open the pavu-controll to select as the source for this program my graphic card.

This time it is different,  I ran cinelerra-gg (which I did not install with apt-get but extracted from a txz file) and had no sound, so I opened pavu controll, but where I can usually select my graphic card is no option to select my gpu.

Why is it so? 
What is different this time?
How do I get the sound to play?

It looks like this, notice no GPU to select:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say you want your graphics card as source? The tab you opened is the "Output" tab (=sink), and there is one graphics card (HDA Nvidia). But the port is "unplugged" - is there another port your audio is connected? Please give more information on your audio configuration.

Comment: sorry, you are absolutely right,  I made the wrong screenshot, however in the Playback part there was no gpu listed either.